# What's the best way to initialize a list of a predefined length?

Tags: vimscript

I need to create a list containing a predefined number of zeros.

I know that I can create an empty one with `let foo = []` but I would need to initialize it with a number of zeros contained in a variable.

[`:h List`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#List) doesn't seem to mention this use case, what's the most efficient way to do that?

---

A second part of my question is about nested lists:

I need to create a list of lists, with the number of inner lists contained in a variable and the length of the inner lists in another variable. (The inner lists are all of the same size)

Is it possible to the method used for one list in this case?
If not how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine the `map` and `range` function for that:

```
:echo map(range(4), 0)
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

`range(4)` returns a list of number defined by the arguments:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

`map([0, 1, 2, 3], 0)` replace every element in the array with `0`

You can use the following function:

```
function! Fill(len, char)
    return map(range(a:len), a:char)
endfunction
```

You can use it like so:

```
:echo Fill(4, 'a')
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```

---

For the recursive fill, you can use the following function:

```
function! FillRecursive(len1, len2, char)
  if a:len2 == -1
    return map(range(a:len1), 'a:char')
  endif

  return map(range(a:len1), 'FillRecursive(a:len2, -1, a:char)')
endfunction
```

You can use it like so:

```
:echo FillRecursive(4,4,'a')
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']]
```

You can see the interesting part in the map: instead of passing the `l:inner` directly, because the `map` function cannot accept a list, but it can accept the literal string containing the list.

Answer (score 5):

```
repeat([0], 4)
```

is what you're looking for.

```
:h repeat()
```

Regarding the inner lists/matrices, we could think about:

```
echo repeat([repeat([0], 5)], 2)
```

however, it will do a shallow copy of the first inner list.  See

```
let t = repeat([repeat([0], 5)], 2)
let t[0][0] = 42
echo t[0]
echo t[1]
```

All inner lists need to be copied. We are back to `map()`+`copy()`. Note that somehow with a more complex need may require the use of `deepcopy()` instead.

```
let t = map(repeat([repeat([0], 5)], 2), 'copy(v:val)')
```